# powershell watcher to run all the time without exit

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm testing file/folder event watcher based on this link

https://www.mobzystems.com/code/using-a-filesystemwatcher-from-powershell/

everything works fine, but when powershell is closed, watcher gets destroyed too, that is a problem, because I want to have a watcher watch folder all the time.

is there any way could achieve that?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to use nssm to run my powershell as a service. Within my powershell I used Start-Process to start the process I was interested in (php.exe) and then my powershell would monitor the PID for that process and do whatever I need (alert if process fails, shutdown the process on script termination, etc.).

Nssm is pretty cool, it's just a .exe you run (no install) to create the service.

For example:

Create a script to run the Watcher

```
# Set up your logging; the stdout and stderr log files have to exist, Start-Process won't create them.

$global:JobID = Start-Process `
    -FilePath 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe  `
    -ArgumentList -File Start-FileSystemWatcher.ps1 -Path <path to watch> `
    -PassThru `
    -RedirectStandardOutput <your stdout log>
    -RedirectStandardError <your stderr log>

# Optional loop to watch the JobID to see if it dies and then alert
# Optional loop to stop the job and rotate the log files; then restart the job
```

You might have some problems with the argurment list. I haven't tried passing named parameters. You might want to throw the params into a hash table and splat that into the Start-Process.

Nssm is easy, this is the command-line version, because I had to do this like, a dozen times and wrote a script to generate the details, rather than fill out 24 different forms:

```
D:\nssm-2.24\win64\nssm.exe install "Watch <folder name> "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"

D:\nssm-2.24\win64\nssm.exe set "Watch <folder name>" AppParameters  -nologo -noexit -noninteractive -noprofile -file <the script created above>

D:\nssm-2.24\win64\nssm.exe set "Watch <folder name>" AppDirectory <the directory you want it to run in (optional)>
```

But you could just run nssm.exe install "Watch 'folder name'" and it will bring up some forms for you fill out, since you are only doing it once.

Comment: is there any non-third party method?

Comment: if using nssm, can you give an example for adding watcher as service? I tried but not work for me

Comment: I have also, once before, written a C++ app to run as a service, which then runs Powershell. NSSM is a lot easier.